# I want to update changes made from a data grid view to my table in my database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i want the save button to save the updated changes ive made to the data grid view to the database. However at the moment the save button is saving as an entirely new row with the updated changes.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter("insert into Student (FName, SName, Attendance, CA1, CA2, FinalExam) values ( '" & txtFName.Text & "','" & txtSName.Text & "',  '" & txtAttendance.Text & "', '" & txtCA1.Text & "', '" & txtCA2.Text & "', '" & txtFinalExam.Text & "' )", dbconn)


    adt.Fill(ds)
    ds = New DataSet
    showData()
    MsgBox("Saved")
```

Comment: You call `Fill` on a data adapter to execute the `SelectCommand` to retrieve data. To save changes, you call `Update` on the same data adapter to execute the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as required. You have to create each those three commands yourself or use a command builder to create them for you.  [See here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=) for examples.

Comment: Never, ever concat variables and/or controls into a SQL query like that.  Use SQL parameters always

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue an update rather than an insert sql command

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp (for a better overview of update)

Comment: your adt = New OLeDBDataAdapter("you have an insert command")

replace it with an update command that looks like


     UPDATE table_name
     SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
     WHERE condition; 


The where condition is needed so it knows what row to update

Comment: @EricYang, that's not going to work. When you create a data adapter like that, whatever SQL statement you pass to it will be used to create the `SelectedCommand`. You have to create an `OleDbCommand` object with the `UPDATE` statement and assign that to the `UpdateCommand` yourself or else use a command builder.

Answer (score 0):

The generic script below will do the insert for you.  Simply change the column names and you are in business.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' Requires: Imports System.Data.OleDb

        ' ensures the connection is closed and disposed
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\DOT.NET\Samples VB\Insert Into MS Access Table from Textbox\WindowsApplication1\bin\InsertInto.mdb"";" & _
            "Persist Security Info=False")
            ' open connection
            connection.Open()

            ' Create command
            Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand( _
                "INSERT INTO Table1([inputOne] , [inputTwo] , [inputThree]) " & _
                "VALUES (@inputOne, @inputTwo, @inputThree);", _
                connection)
            ' Add the parameters with value
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputOne", TextBox1.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputTwo", TextBox2.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputThree", TextBox3.Text)
            ' you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
            ' execute the command
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Insert is done!!")

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

HTH.